# Hover and Focus privilege in Emotion-styled in React

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
export const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)(({ error }) => ({
  '.MuiInputBase-root': {
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: '4px',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    paddingRight: '12px',
    paddingLeft: '12px',
  },
  '.MuiInputBase-input': {
    height: '100%',
    padding: '0px',
    border: '0px',
    paddingRight: '0px',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  '.MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
    height: '100%',
    paddingRight: '12px',
    paddingLeft: '12px',
    border: 'none',
    left: '12',
    '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      border: ` ${
        error
          ? '2px solid var(--error-600, #EE5350)'
          : '1px solid var(--gray-200, #DFE4E8)'
      } `,
    },
    '&:hover': {
      '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
        border: ` ${
          error ? '2px solid var(--error-600, #EE5350)' : '1px solid green'
        }`,
      },
    },
    '&:focus': {
      '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
        border: `2px solid ${
          error ? 'var(--error-600, #EE5350)' : 'var(--primary-500, #154AB6)'
        }`,
      },
    },
  },
}));
```

When I hover and focus at the same time, the focus format just doesn't work.

I hope that when I hover over the TextField while it is in a focused state, it behaves as if it is in focus rather than just hovering.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.